# When does the NSBlock get freed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsblockoperation

In a view controller I have a property of NSBlock of copy type as follow

```
@interface myViewController
@property(nonatomic, copy) MyBlock *block;
@end

@implementation myViewController

@end
```

When my application pop from myViewController then my block will be release automatically?

**Note:** My project is ARC enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block is deallocated when the view controller is deallocated. Whether the view controller is deallocated on pop or not depends on your app.

Anyway, `dealloc` on the view controller -> destruction of the block. Unless you've shared the block pointer with other objects in your view controller code, of course.

Comment: Or unless there is a retaining cycle inside the block!

Comment: Indeed! Beware of block related retain cycles in view controller - beware of a block property than references `self`.

Comment: I am sure that only weakself is used inside of block definition. so there is no retain cycles.

Comment: The compiler will usually trip over trivial block-assigning cycles. Plenty of room for mistakes though!